# MIgrate data from SQL Server to Bluemix Database as a Service

Tags: sql-server, database, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to move data from a local SQL Server 2014 database to Bluemix's database as a service. The IBM SQL database console limits uploads to 20 MB.  Some of my tables are significantly larger than that.

What would be the best way to move the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you install the DB2 client on your local machine, you can connect directly to your SQLDB database and use the `IMPORT` or `LOAD`** utilities to load the data.

For example,

```
load client from /tmp/mssql.cust.csv of del replace into my_table
```

** With `LOAD`, you have to use `LOAD CLIENT ...` in order to load data from your client machine instead of the server.

Comment: I have Data Stuiod and clpplus.  Where would I run this command?  Thanks!